# How to display videos on tkinter using sequence of images

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a GUI that displays sequence of images as videos. The images are numpy arrays.

The code is working when I try to display one image at a time but it crashes when I try to run them as a sequence.

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
from scipy.io import loadmat
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time
data = loadmat('DepthFrames.mat')['DepthFrames'].squeeze(axis=0)
print(data.shape)
counter = 0
root = Tk()
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(data[counter]))
root.title("WUDU VIDEOS LABEL TOOL")
myLabel = Label(root, image = image)
myLabel.grid(row = 0)
def changeImg():
    global counter
    counter +=1
    print(counter)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(data[counter]))
    myLabel.configure(image = image)
    myLabel.image = image

def playVideo():
    for i in range(10):
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(data[i]))
        myLabel.configure(image = image)
        myLabel.image = image
        time.sleep(0.03333)
my_Button = Button(text = "Play video",command = playVideo)
my_Button.grid(row = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.sleep` blocks the main thread of `tkinter`. Your code will freeze the GUI until the `for` loop is completed and the image will be shown as the last image. For more details, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31591999/9284423) post.

You need to use the [`after`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method. Something like this:

```
def playVideo(frame=0):
    try:
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = Image.fromarray(data[frame]))
    except IndexError:
        return
    myLabel.configure(image = image)
    myLabel.image = image
    root.after(33, playVideo, frame+1)
```